# SQL query looks OK in management studio but throws memory exception when building reports by Data Tools

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I have fours SQL tables (with different number of rows and column) from those I want to build a new table for reporting purpose based on some rules. I built query statements and run in management studio. In this case, I get some response from management studio with some data but if I try to use those SQL queries in data source to build a report in Visual Studio, I get memory exception. What can I do for this? 
Here is the SQL statements I used

```
SELECT Intable.Fra, EqTable.Name, Rf.Data
  FROM EqTable,InTable,RfTable
  WHERE RfTable.Name = EqTable.Name  AND EqTable.Name] NOT LIKE '%Ann%';
```

The equivalent tables are shown in the following diagram.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried creating a view with that query? That might work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two possibilities:

- You have an additional "]" character included in your SQL but this maybe a typo
- Do you need a join for the table [inTable]?

Comment: I could not use join here because there is no match in ID(I have limited knowledge in SQL). Could you show me how can I use join here? Thanks

Comment: Without knowing what your schema is - no sorry.  Your expanded result set will be the result of a cartesian join which will inflate the amount of results returned either correctly or incorrectly.  [See google](https://www.google.co.uk/?ion=1&espv=2#q=cartesian%20join)

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly because you are using the ANSI-89 style join. You should use the "newer" ANSI-92 style join.

- [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

What has happened here is you have joined RfTable and EqTable by Name. But then you have created a cross join to InTable. The memory exception is probably because once you create this cross join the amount of rows is staggering.

What I really don't understand though is you said you have 4 tables but only 3 of them are in your query.

Comment: I have shown 3 tables but in actual code I have 4 tables.

Comment: So the query you posted isn't the query that you are actually using? How do you expect anybody to be able to help when you don't even give them correct information?

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to avoid actual code other wise it is same.

Comment: Well then use proper join syntax and avoid the cross joins. When you run your query in SSMS how many rows are you getting back?

Comment: Thanks, with my actual database I get 1490535 rows With SSMS it looks fine. Since most online examples hows if there are matches in Keys then join works and in my case there are no matches in ID, so I am confused.

Comment: So you are getting almost 1.5 million rows and trying to stick those on a report? There is the problem. If you get 80 rows of results on a page that is 18,632 pages. That many pieces of paper would require you to purchase 38 reams of paper or the equivalent of 5 cases. That isn't a report. That is a data dump. You need to drastically reduce the amount of data here.

Comment: Good points, I just checked after your comment though SSMS gives me some results but those are not correct result.

Comment: OK. Well if you actually want some help you need provide some details. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Thanks for the tips, actually if I use DISTINCT it looks both Visual studio and SSMS give some results, at least visual studio does not complain about memory exception and the rows are 97740 . Now need to check if it gives me valid result.

Comment: If you are being forced to use distinct then there is probably something wrong with your query.